# Build error in Visual Studio Web App with Version Control

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ankhsvn

I am working on a C# Web Application that I have checked out with AnkhSVN. After checking the program out, I do a build there are no problems. But once I make a change and do another build or debug there are several errors. However, my colleagues are not having this same issue. What I have noticed is that after the build all of the items (ie .cs files) are converted to templates. They were built from scratch. Why would my Visual Studio be converting these files to templates? It's throwing off the ADO.NET Self-Tracking Entity Generator.

Some of the errors include:

Error   1   Compiling transformation: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating6369C9141E45365CBFAAE9A73F25AA47.GeneratedTextTransformation.MetadataTools' does not contain a definition for 'NeedsHandleCascadeDeleteMethod' and no extension method 'NeedsHandleCascadeDeleteMethod' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating6369C9141E45365CBFAAE9A73F25AA47.GeneratedTextTransformation.MetadataTools' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   c:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\XXXXXXXXXX\XXXXXXXX\BlackbookDB.tt 428 12

Comment: So BlackbookDb.tt was original a *.cs file?  Is it actually getting renamed to *.tt in your project, or is that changed filename only showing up in the error?

Comment: The other question would be what is the changes you are making, as it doesn't break until you make a change.  Not that I'm saying you are doing something wrong, but that might be an indicator.

Comment: @AaronLS I'm adding a stored procedure from a SQL Server DB.
No BlackbookDB.tt is a Self Tracking entity. Other .cs files are getting converted to a template.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the build action set in the properties of the file is Compile and not something else.